# Problems with layout using <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion - Android

Tags: android, apk

I was publishing my first APP but i have a problem, I have tested my app with a lot of AVD then i tested with my phone(Galaxy S) and with my girlfriend phone (Galaxy 5) before publishing, when i tried to publish i received a msg to specify an API level requirement.  then i put this code

```
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" 
              android:targetSdkVersion="7"
             />
```

then i tested in the AVD and i had no problem, but when i publish and tested in my Galaxy S, i encountered a crazy layout of my app, i do no why, so i go back to the Eclipse and tested direct to my galaxy S and get the same error, so i take this part of the code out and then tried again in my galaxy S and the layout is all OK, so i`m probably doing some thing wrong.

Many Thanks Sorry my poor English i`m from Brazil.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is do with your layout defintion. What values have you used for layout_width and layout_height? (for layout and widgets)? You should use "wrap_content" of "fill_parent" and if you are forced to give exacts, give values in dip (100dip) rather than px or pix. Read this doco for more details http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: i changed all my px to dip and now is all OK =D

Answer (score 0):

It may be because your 2 phones have different android versions. Do this, create 2 emulators with exact same android version, screen size and density as your 2 phones and test and debug there.

Answer (score 0):

Leave the minSDK declaration and get rid of the target SDK.  You are using two separate declarations.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4"/>
```

This is the only one you need.

Answer (score -1):

I have seen this too. My app runs on everything from api level 4 and up. When I add

`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4"/>`

to my manifest and run on my G2 I get a crazy layout. Thanks for this heads-up. I will report later on the changes I had to make.

m.